# Why isn't this recursion working in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, return

I am trying to calculate the factorial of the integer user inputs, but it does not return anything. Why?

Thanks.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

`class App {

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int recurse = factorial(n - 1);
            int result = n * recurse;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate its factorial: ");
        int users = input.nextInt();

        factorial(users);

    }
}
```

Comment: it probably does but you are not printing or showing the result in some way

Comment: System.out.println("factorial = " + factorial(users));

Comment: Doesn't return statement save me from using sysout?

Comment: Write what Shark said in method main, replacing the line factorial(users)

Comment: @AliJ., no, not if you want the return value printed. You need to read up on returning values from methods.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it returns 0 when the user inputs larger than 33, and negative value when entered 32 and 33. It must have something to do with types, I guess.

Comment: You are correct. A Java `int` has 32 bits in its implementation and can hold numbers up to a little over 2 billion. This is enough for factorials up to `factorial(12)`, meaning that you will get incorrect results for `factorial(13)` and greater because of integer overflow. `factorial(34)` is special in that the binary representation of that number ends in 32 zeroes. Despite the overflow, Java calculates the last 32 bits correctly, so the result in a 32 bit `int` is — 0, zero.

Comment: To calculate higher factorials you may use `long`, `double` or `BigInteger`. `double` will give you inaccurate results, though, but they may be good enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you are have not giving a print statement for displaying factorial of the number entered. Just returning a value will not print it. If you are working in BlueJ environment, you can only use the code by directly executing the method factorial. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem in your code is that , you are have not given a print statement for >displaying factorial of the number entered.